# How to set a link to open in safari Phonegap Build 3.0.0

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

I am using phonegap build and setting my version to 3.0.0. I have link on my page that I would like to open in safari on iOS. In my config file I have my access orgin set to "*" so it allows all urls (this is necessary for other parts of my app). I also have the inappbrowser plugin in my config file as I was told this might be necessary.

```
<access origin="*" /> 
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.core.inappbrowser" />
```

I am currently using the following code to set my "a" tag:

```
$('#myATagID').on('click', function () {
            window.open(encodeURI('http://apache.org'), '_system', 'location=no');
        });
```

I've tried many different attempts at getting this url to open in safari on my iPhone, but none have been successful with phonegap build 3.0.0    This code does work on android though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my SO answer on this subject located [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18675861/external-links-in-phonegap-app-do-not-open-well/18697241#18697241). Full walkthrough you should find relevant.

Comment: No longer working in Phonegap 3. The documentation suggests window.open is totally tied with the InApp browser, and never mentions breaking out of the webview and into a new app (Safari).

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need the plugin just to open in a system browser.  I use the following JavaScript function to perform the same task.

JavaScript:

```
// window.open wasn't opening a link in the system browser on iOS, so we have to use this function (requires phonegap.js)
function redirectToSystemBrowser(url) {
    // Wait for Cordova to load
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);
    // Cordova is ready
    function onDeviceReady() {
        // open URL in default web browser
        var ref = window.open(encodeURI(url), '_system', 'location=yes');
    }
}
```

Then, I simply call that function with HTML.

HTML:

```
<head>
    <!-- required for the redirectToSystemBrowser() function -->
    <script src="phonegap.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <ul>
        <li onclick="redirectToSystemBrowser('http://www.domain.ext');">link to something</li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

Also, I didn't specify any `<access>` settings (I just commented them all out).

Comment: Oh, and Dom's answer is a much more complete and informative answer (I plussed it, as such).  Hehehe...

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to remove the `encodeURI()`, because, this may encode the // and make the URI malformed.

Comment: encodeURI won't encode //. [See here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuri.asp).

Answer (score 0):

To open an external link in Safari you need the In App Browser plugin

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/blob/master/doc/index.md

This you call window.open(encodeURI("https://google.com"), "_system");

"_blank" will load it in the in a modal browser within the app.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
window.open('http://google.com', '_system', 'location=no');
```

Works well for me.