# phonegap android application webrowser

Tags: android, cordova

I know about phonegap but here i am want to know if it 
is possible to have an android application which is not 
really an application but merely a browser that opens only
a particular webpage, that is only the mobile site i already 
designed, am not sure but i have seen some android apps and i know
they do something similar , below are the things i want :

- The app should be installable.
- Just opens a link to an existing webpage online.i.e its more like a browser
  only it just opens only a specified web page

is this possible with Phonegap for Android ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that. You would want to use the inappbrowser plugin to open an external page when ondeviceready is fired. Take a look at my SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18675861/external-links-in-phonegap-app-do-not-open-well/18697241#18697241) for a guide on how to use the inappbrowser, and you can take a look [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#deviceready) for the docs about ondeviceready.