# Phonegap external url wildcard

Tags: android, jquery, html, cordova, apk

I have spent 27 hours last 2 days and been on nearly all google/stackoverflow links so please write some important information and not just link similar questions, I really need this fixed.

Im building an very easy application for iOS and Android using phonegap.
But when build.phonegap.com builds the project it does not configure it correctly and I can't import external url to my app.

A very simply test and one of 100 things i have test and feel should work is:

Index.html 
standard js files included etc.
Then a simple external image.

```
<img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png">
```

config.xml

```
<access origin="*" /> 
<allow-intent href="*" />
```

Works great in the www folder, but when build.phonegap.com builds the .apk  it seems like the application does not have rights to open external URL's.

> AndroidManifest.xml  has  android.permission.INTERNET

I have also tested with jquery to .load(url); into an div, however I feel like I need to have permission from the .apk to use internetacess.
buid.phonegap.com creates the AndroidManifest.xml/info.plist but if i edit those I break the keychain for cerfificates to google play/app store.

What can I have missed?

Comment: READ, [External links in phonegap app do not open well](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33193257/3255670). Also, it is bad practice to source your assets from the internet. They should all be on the device.

Comment: I have installed and include the whitelist in my XML. Still same problem.
Refereing to the assets it was just an example to try load an external link item.

Comment: Did you implement the CSP?

Answer (score 0):

in newer version you need to add and configure https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist

Comment: I am aware of this, and I also think the problem is located in the whitelist, because it works with a lower phonegap version. However I have included the whitelist plugin, and inserted the acess, allow-intent and allow-navigation. All those set to  = "*" while testing to allow full permissions.